# images url are not displaying in grid

Tags: android, image, gridview

I have set a gridview for image url..I can't able to see the image in grid.. Just shows the background...and on click the grid plays in next screen.

What im doing wrong? How to implement this?

Thanks a lot in advance

my code

> ```
>     public class act extends Activity {
> static  String uri1="https://i3.ytimg.com/vi/bQaWsVQSLdY/default.jpg";
> static String uri2="https://i4.ytimg.com/vi/cJQCniWQdno/mqdefault.jpg";
> static String uri3="https://i1.ytimg.com/vi/D8dA4pE5hEY/mqdefault.jpg";
> public static String[] urls={uri1,uri2,uri3};
> public Bitmap bitmap;
> @Override
> public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.main);
>     GridView grd=(GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
>     grd.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
>     grd.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
>     {
>     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,View v,int pos,long id)
>     {
>         Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"pic"+(pos+1)+"select ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>     }
>     });
> }
> public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter
> {
>     private Context context;
>     private int itemBackground;
>     ImageAdapter(Context c)
>     {
>     context=c;
>     TypedArray a=obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.Gallery1);
>     itemBackground=a.getResourceId(R.styleable.Gallery1_android_galleryItemBackground,0);
>     a.recycle();
>     }
>     public int getCount()
>     {
>         return urls.length;
>     }
>     public Object getItem(int pos)
>     {
>         return pos;
>     }
>     public long getItemId(int pos)
>     {
>         return pos;
>     }
>     public View getView(int pos,View cv,ViewGroup vg)
>     {
> Bitmap bitmap=  DownloadImage( urls[pos] );
> ImageView imageview=new ImageView(context);
> imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
> return cv;    
>     }
> private Bitmap DownloadImage(String URL)
>     {        
>         final String URL1=URL;       
>         new Thread()
>         {
>             public void run()
>             {               
>                 InputStream in = null;  
>                 Message msg = Message.obtain();
>                 msg.what = 1;
>                 try {
>                     in = OpenHttpConnection(URL1);
>                     Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);     
>                     Bundle b = new Bundle();
>                     b.putParcelable("bitmap", bitmap);
>                     msg.setData(b);
>                     in.close();
>                 } catch (IOException e1) {
>                     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
>                     e1.printStackTrace();
>                 }
>             }
>         }.start();
>         return bitmap;
>     }
>     private InputStream OpenHttpConnection(String urlString)
>             throws IOException
>             {
>                 InputStream in = null;
>                 int response = -1;
>                 URL url = new URL(urlString);
>                 URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
>                 if (!(conn instanceof HttpURLConnection))                    
>                     throw new IOException("Not an HTTP connection");
>                 try{
>                     HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
>                     httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
>                     httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
>                     httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
>                     httpConn.connect();
>                     response = httpConn.getResponseCode();                
>                     if (response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) 
>                     {
>                         in = httpConn.getInputStream();                                
>                     }                    
>                 }
>                 catch (Exception ex)
>                 {
>                     throw new IOException("Error connecting");            
>                 }
>                 return in;    
>     }
> }
> }
> ```

logcat

> ```
>      E/AndroidRuntime(832): java.lang.NullPointerException
>        E/AndroidRuntime(832):   at android.widget.GridView.onMeasure(GridView.java:937)
>         E/AndroidRuntime(832):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
>        E/AndroidRuntime(832):   at 
>        android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
>        E/AndroidRuntime(832):   at 
>        android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1017)
>         E/AndroidRuntime(832):  at 
>         android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:386)
>          E/AndroidRuntime(832):     at 
>         android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
>          E/AndroidRuntime(832):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
>          E/AndroidRuntime(832):     at 
>          android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
>           E/AndroidRuntime(832):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
>          E/AndroidRuntime(832):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
>          E/AndroidRuntime(832):     at 
>           android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:531)
>           E/AndroidRuntime(832):    at 
>           android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
>           E/AndroidRuntime(832):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
>           E/AndroidRuntime(832):    at 
>           android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
>           E/AndroidRuntime(832):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
>           E/AndroidRuntime(832):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
>           E/AndroidRuntime(832):    at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:839)
>           E/AndroidRuntime(832):    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1859)
>           E/AndroidRuntime(832):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>            E/AndroidRuntime(832):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
>            E/AndroidRuntime(832):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
>            E/AndroidRuntime(832):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>            E/AndroidRuntime(832):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
>            E/AndroidRuntime(832):   at 
>            com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
>             E/AndroidRuntime(832):  at 
>            com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
>             E/AndroidRuntime(832):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
> ```

Comment: my out put is like that..see in screenshot

Comment: you have to download that images from server after that show in grid view. http://stackoverflow.com/a/3068012/1168654

Comment: my code will works are not..what mistake im doing..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code i tried ..Images are displaying..You customize the grid view as your need.You just copy and paste the below code in your activity  and try..

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    static  String uri1="http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/bQaWsVQSLdY/default.jpg";
    static String uri2="http://i4.ytimg.com/vi/cJQCniWQdno/mqdefault.jpg";
    static String uri3="http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/D8dA4pE5hEY/mqdefault.jpg";
    public static String[] urls={uri1,uri2,uri3};
//  public Bitmap bitmap;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        GridView grd=(GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridview1);
        grd.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));


    }
    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {
        private Context context;
        private int itemBackground;
        ImageAdapter(Context c)
        {
        context=c;    
        }
        public int getCount()
        {
            return urls.length;
        }
        public Object getItem(int pos)
        {
            return pos;
        }
        public long getItemId(int pos)
        {
            return pos;
        }

    private Bitmap DownloadImage(String URL)
        {        
             String URL1=URL; 
             Bitmap bitmap = null;
//          new Thread()
//          {
//              public void run()
//              {               
                    InputStream in = null;  
                    Message msg = Message.obtain();
                    msg.what = 1;
                    try {
                        in = OpenHttpConnection(URL1);
                        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);     
                        Bundle b = new Bundle();
                        b.putParcelable("bitmap", bitmap);
                        msg.setData(b);
                        in.close();
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
//              }
//          }.start();
            return bitmap;
        }
        private InputStream OpenHttpConnection(String urlString)
                throws IOException
                {
//          System.out.println("Insdie conn");
                    InputStream in = null;
                    int response = -1;
                    URL url = new URL(urlString);
                    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
                    if (!(conn instanceof HttpURLConnection))                    
                        throw new IOException("Not an HTTP connection");
                    try{
//                      System.out.println("Inside try");
                        HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
                        httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
                        httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
//                      httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                        httpConn.connect();
                        response = httpConn.getResponseCode();  
//                      System.out.println("res="+response);
//                      System.out.println("cccccc="+HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK);
                        if (response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) 
                        {
//                          System.out.println("Inside if");
                            in = httpConn.getInputStream();                                
                        }                    
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        throw new IOException("Error connecting");            
                    }
                    return in;    
        }
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View cv, ViewGroup parent) 
        {
            ImageView imageview = null;
//          System.out.println("vvvv="+urls[position]);
            Bitmap bitmap=  DownloadImage( urls[position] );        
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(cv == null)
            {
//              cv=LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.gridviewitem, null);
                imageview =  new ImageView(context);
            }
            else 
            {
                imageview = (ImageView) cv;
            }

            imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            return imageview;    
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ya you  have to add <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />  as direct child of application tag..

Comment: ok i accept sure ur help is great for me....but im not getting the third image...why?

Comment: Cahnge the xml like this .. <GridView 
   android:id="@+id/gridView1"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
   </LinearLayout>

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing your `getView()` with this and let me know the result:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    private Context context;
    private int itemBackground;
    public ImageLoader imageLoader; 

    ImageAdapter(Context c)
    {
    context=c;
    TypedArray a=obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.Gallery1);
    itemBackground=a.getResourceId(R.styleable.Gallery1_android_galleryItemBackground,0);
    a.recycle();
    imageLoader=new ImageLoader(context);
    }
    public int getCount()
    {
        return urls.length;
    }
    public Object getItem(int pos)
    {
        return pos;
    }
    public long getItemId(int pos)
    {
        return pos;
    }
      public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
       ImageView imageView;
             if (convertView == null) {
               imageView = new ImageView(context);
               imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
               imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
               imageView.setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);
    } else {
             imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

       imageLoader.DisplayImage(urls[position], imageView)
       return imageView;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here Is [Example](https://github.com/desertjim/LazyLoadingGridView) of `GridView` With `ImageLoading`

Edited:

noting is wrong in you code. but you are tying to show image from server(online its not in you application resources or in sdcard, gallery etc..) thats why its not showing in your GridView. so, you have to download that images from server. after that you have to show them in GridView. i have give you link above how to download images and show them in GridView.

Comment: in array what order is.. that same order i should get in listview.. how to do

Comment: same as listview can't understand

Comment: you have download that example??