# Loading images from URL instead if locally

Tags: android

I've managed to set up loading images from the drawable directory(locally) successfully, and I'm thinking of changing it so it will load the images from the web instead.

I am displaying the images in a GridView, what would I have to do to my code to load them from the web instead?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Adapter:

```
package com.question;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class AdapterViewADV extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;


public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
    R.drawable.Image1,
    R.drawable.Image2,
    R.drawable.Image3,
    R.drawable.Image4,
    R.drawable.Image5,
    R.drawable.Image6

};


public AdapterViewADV(Context c){
mContext = c;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mThumbIds.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
return mThumbIds[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(NO_SELECTION, NO_SELECTION));
return imageView;
}

}
```

Comment: https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Comment: What you tried to make it dynamic ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Download image for imageview on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8423987/download-image-for-imageview-on-android)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the below examples for that....

http://www.ethemsulan.com/2011/05/how-to-load-internet-images-in-gridview-android-sample-2.html

https://github.com/desertjim/LazyLoadingGridView

https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

https://github.com/koush/UrlImageViewHelper

[Lazy load of images in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview)

[images url are not displaying in grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16212883/images-url-are-not-displaying-in-grid)

Try these examples you can get some ideas...